# In JMeter SMTP sampler give AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

### Actually manually my gmail account proper open but SMTP sampler give the error, PLZ help me and give me a answer.

### Sampler Result :

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-02-01 10:49:54 IST
Load time: 3032
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 16
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 16
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: AuthenticationFailedException: authentication failed - wrong username / password!
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14  Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 m86sm39534293pfi.27 - gsmtp

Response headers:

SampleResult fields:
ContentType:

### DataEncoding: null

SMTP Sampler ScreenShoot :
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Make sure that enable below mentioned setting for your gmail account
**1.**You need to TURNED ON Less secure apps
```

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

```
**2.**Allow each app to send email Go to
```

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

```
And click on Continue.
Now try to execute your thread.
```

Comment: Automatically execute Test scenarios and send all test result status as a report via "mail" .                                                                                          It is possible or not.                                                                                       It's possible so please give a answer.

Comment: yes,if you  will add this thread on your execution test plan 
And need to save your results in a particular folder and pass that path over "Attach file" colunm

Comment: For this purpose you can use "tearDown Thread Group". This type of thread group will execute at the end only

Comment: Please give me a all detail actually i can't understand above comment. Please describe all steps

Comment: Actually i am use the "Run tearDown Thread Group" and "Run Thread Groups consecutively " option, but and send the Test report via mail.                                                                                                             Send only subject line and  Message but not send the test result report.

Comment: I think you got the answer in your other question with details regarding "Automatically execute Test scenarios and send all test result status as a report via "mail"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128591/automatically-execute-test-scenarios-and-send-all-test-result-status-as-a-report/35129315#35129315

Comment: For saving your result to a particular path you need to add "Aggregate Report" in you main thread and in "File Name"  column you need to pass path with file name.

Comment: Hello Vikas Plz give a your contact no. , I have one query