# Automatically execute Test scenarios and send all test result status as a report via "mail".

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

- Automatically execute Test scenarios and send all test result status as a report via "mail".
- It is possible or not.
- It's possible so, please give a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible,
A simple technique is you need to add "**SMTP Sampler**" inside the `tearDown Thread Group` and add that thread group at the end of your `Test Plan`.

For that make sure:

1. In Test Plan `Run tearDown Thread Group after shutdown of main threads` check box need to "**check**".
2. Save your main thread results in a particular folder and pass that path over "Attach file" column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (it is located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

otherwise results file might be incomplete and use JMeter's [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) to send .jtl results file as attachment to specified account or mailing list.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of working with them.