# Jmeter - SMTP Sampler doesn't run at all

Tags: api, smtp, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter for API test. the test divided into two Thread Groups, each sends email through SMTP Sampler at the end of it. for some reason, the first SMTP Sampler doesn't run at all (although it used to). I don't think I've changed anything in it, and it is enabled. when looking at the 'View Results Tree' of the Sampler - I don't see anything. like it skips it.

[image: my Jmeter structure]

Comment: If "Drive API" (whatever that controller is) or one of the commands under it fails or hangs, SMTP Sampler will not run. So did you check that plan indeed exits from "Drive API" controller? Also any exceptions in the log?

Comment: actually I do get some warning: 016/02/07 22:46:37 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.SmtpSampler:  javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1245)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.protocol.SendMailCommand.execute(SendMailCommand.java:293)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.SmtpSampler.sample(SmtpSampler.java:235)
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
 at org.apache.jmeter.th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file that I was sending with the email message was too big.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am assuming that you are entering all correct details over SMTP Sampler
field's. still Once check them and go through below mention link, may be
that will help you.
```

1. > [In JMeter SMTP sampler give AuthenticationFailedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123497/in-jmeter-smtp-sampler-give-authenticationfailedexception/35127144?noredirect=1#comment57980211_35127144)
2. > [Automatically execute Test scenarios and send all test result status as a report via "mail".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128591/automatically-execute-test-scenarios-and-send-all-test-result-status-as-a-report/35129315#35129315)